# Highcharts stacked bar with datetime, not able to set start date

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts, stacked

I'm trying to use a stacked bar to represent up/down status over time. For some reason, I'm not able to get the start date to work correctly.

This is what I'm going for, but the start date won't update past epoch start. 
http://jsfiddle.net/t5d72ka5/4/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        backgroundColor:'transparent',
        zoomType:'y'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
    },
    yAxis: {
        //min: 1502236800000 or min: Date.UTC(2011, 4, 31) 
        type: 'datetime',
        "tickInterval": 86400000,
        "minTickInterval": 86400000,
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            day: '%Y %b %e'
        },
        title: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [
    {
        name: 'down',
        data: [83621000],
        color: 'red'
    }, {
        name: 'up',
        data: [83621000],
        color: 'green'
    }, {
        name: 'down',
        data: [83621000],
        color: 'red'
    }, {
        name: 'up',
        data: [83621000],
        color: 'green'
    }]
});
```

I've tried to add the start date in min: 1502236800000 or with UTC and while it sets the start date right, the data doesn't render.

Also tried a few other things with the data values, pointStart, etc. but can't this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that `threshold` option is what you're looking for:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      threshold: 1502236800000
    }
  },
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jyjfvoac/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.threshold